# Does Plone 4.1 use KSS? Can I disabled JS and CSS files associated with KSS safely?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, kss

Does Plone 4.1 use KSS? Can I disable JS and CSS files associated with KSS safely?

I see this in the documentation:
http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/javascript.html?highlight=kss#id27

but my Plone 4.1 site still loads files as `ploneKss.css`, `at.kss`, `plone.kss`, etc. Is the plone site still functional (working) without these files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable them. You'll lose some progressive enhancement features (ability to drag files to reorder on the Contents tab, for example), but the site should still be usable.

Or you can upgrade to Plone 4.3, which no longer uses KSS.